# Edit commands for icon launcher

Tags: application, kubuntu

I am having an issue with `Kompozer` and as per [a recommendation](https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12734) I am now launching it (from command line) with `OXYGEN_APPLICATION_NAME_OVERRIDE=xulrunner kompozer`. I was (previously) launching the `Kompozer` app with an icon launcher, but that launcher does not include the needed `xulrunner` override. I would rather not have to launch it from command line each time, so how can I edit that icon launcher to take into account this new option?

I am using Kubuntu 14.04 if it matters.